# no toolbar gem trix rails 6.0.3.2 ruby 2.7.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, trix

[image][image: Empty Trix gem bar]

No visible icons of the Trix bar.
I have added into `head` tag **app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="trix.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="trix.js"></script>
```

and added `*= require trix` into **app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss**

here is my body code

```
div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :body %>
  <%= f.text_area :body, class: 'form-control' %>
  <trix-editor input="post_body"></trix-editor>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think an easier way to install the trix editor in a Rails 6 app would be to install it via action text:

```
rails action_text:install
```

I believe this will also install `active_storage`, but if not, you can also run:

```
rails active_storage:install
```

In your model, you add:

```
has_rich_text :body
```

And in your view:

```
<%= f.rich_text_area :body %>
```

You can remove `body` from your model, as it is no longer needed there. You also have to add `body` to your permitted params, but is should already be there since it is in your table.

You can read more about action_text [here](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_text_overview.html).

Comment: Already did it. But now I'm trying ro find, how to add uploaded picture on tge post preview

Comment: Is active_storage installed? Did the picture upload?

Comment: Yes. I can see the pucture, when open current post, but can't find some info how to add it on preview

Comment: What do you mean by 'add it on preview'?

Comment: To see the same picture, but smaller and near the post title

Comment: Ah. You have to install the `image_processing` gem to manipulate the picture.

Comment: Check picture. Wanna to make like that. Have installed that gem.

Comment: Let's move to chat.